# How to link *.so file in AIX with GCC compiler

Tags: c, gcc, linker, aix

I am trying to link a *.so file while compiling a C code using GCC compiler on AIX machine but could not do so. Using traditional `-L` and `-l` options, for path and .so library name respectively, gives "could not find error", setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` didn't help either. I understand that linking options are different in AIX. But I'm not able to comprehend the correct options.

Can you please answer my query with example.

Answer (score 1):

Use option `-Wl,-brtl` to be able to use `*so*` shared objects.

Edit (the first option is either `-maix32` or `-maix64` depending on the context):

```
gcc -maix32 -o example -Wl,-brtl example.c /var/tmp/lib/librequired.so
```

or

```
gcc -maix32 -o example -Wl,-brtl example.c -L/var/tmp/lib -lrequired
```

Comment: I used this option but got "not a coff file" error. Let's say I have a library file "librequired.so" at path "/var/tmp/lib" and a C file "example.c" with "example.h" header file. Now can you please tell me what can be the complete gcc command. thanks

Comment: @Sandeep then it's probably not a coff file. What does `file /var/tmp/lib/librequired.so` say?